# Zorin 17. Sound issues with Audacity

Tags: audio, recording, audacity, zorin

I recently dumped Windows & installed Zorin OS 17 so I’m a greenhorn as far as Linux goes.
So far it’s all going rather well except for a few minor issues, most of which I’ve been able to solve. However, I’ve come unstuck with regard to sound. I use an AudioBox USB as my audio interface which works well for playing music & sound in general but I want to use Audacity for recording sound from the PC. In Audacity audio setup the Host is set to ALSA (unchangeable). I’ve selected ‘AudioBox USB: Audio(hw:1,0) for my recording device but AudioBox isn’t available as a  playback device.
Unfortunately this doesn’t work when attempting to record sound I’m hearing in the speakers.
I’ve tried using the built-in Sound Recorder & that doesn’t record either.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Problem solved! I installed PulseAudio Volume Control which allowed me to see what was going on. With a couple of adjustments it now works as expected.